# Find all items in a list that match a specific format

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to find everything in a list that has an format like "######-##"

I thought I had the right idea in my following code, but it isn't printing anything. Some values in my list have that format, and I would think it should print it. Could you tell me what's wrong?

```
for line in list_nums:
    if (line[-1:].isdigit()):
        if (line[-2:-1].isdigit()):
            if (line[-6:-5].isdigit()):
                if ("-" in line[-3:-2]):
                    print(list_nums)
```

The values in my list consist of formats like 123456-56 and 123456-98-98, which is why what I did above. It is pulled from an excel sheet.

**This is my updated code.**

```
import xlrd
from re import compile, match

file_location = "R:/emily/emilylistnum.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
regexp = compile(r'^\d{d}-\d{2}$')
list_nums = ""


for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = sheet.cell_value(row,0)
    if regexp.match(cell):
        list_nums += cell + "\n"
        print(list_nums)
```

**my excel sheet consists of:** 
581094-001
581095-001
581096-001
581097-01
5586987-007
SMX53-5567-53BP
552392-01-01
552392-02
552392-03-01
552392-10-01
552392-10-01
580062
580063
580065
580065
580066
543921-01
556664-55

(in each cell down in one column)

Comment: you can just count the number of dashes in the string, right? So, `if line.count('-') == 2: print(line)`

Comment: I think better solution is to use `re.findall()`. Let's say you `my_string = ''.join(list_nums)`. All you have to do is to `found_elements = re.findall('\d+-\d\d', my_string)`. Please note that `\d+-\d\d` may not be correct. Check https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html for more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to only match the pattern `######-##` (where `#` is a digit):

```
>>> from re import compile, match
>>> regexp = compile(r'^\d{6}-\d{2}$')
>>> print([line for line in list_nums if regexp.match(line)])
['132456-78']
```

---

## Explanations

You `compile` the pattern into a regexp object to be more efficient when matching. The regexp is `^\d{6}-\d{2}$` where:

```
^  # start of the line
\d{6}-\d{2}  # 6 digits, one dot then 2 digits
$  # end of the line
```

In the regexp, `\d` means digit (an integer from 0 to 9) and `{6}` means 6 times. So `\d{3}` means 3 digits. You should read the Python documentation about [regexp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)s.

---

## Full code

An example based on your comment:

```
file_location = 'file.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
regexp = compile(r'^\d{6}-\d{2}$')

list_nums = ''
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    if regexp.match(cell):
        list_nums += cell + "\n"
```

Comment: i only need to find the ones that look like 123456-45, not the 123456-94-94 nor 123456 nor 123456-001

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere with this. However, it is not working for my code.

    import os, sys, xlrd

     file_location = "R:/EXAMPLE DELETE ME Copy of  example for     emily .xlsx"
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    list_nums = ""


for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    list_nums += str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0)) + "\n"
# print(list_nums)

from re import compile, match
regexp = compile(r'\d{6}-\d{2}$')
print(line for line in list_nums if regexp.match(line))

Comment: See the entire regexp, there are `^` before and `$` after to delimit the `line`.

Comment: fixed that. this is what i get : <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000035A2FC0>

Comment: I don't think i understand @Tiger-222

Comment: i pulled all of this data from an excel sheet and i made it a string. then i want to make a new string of ONLY the format i said above. what you just did does more with the excel sheet... i don't think i need to do that.

Comment: You do what you want instead of `print(cell)`. I updated a last time, you should be able to adapt the code :)

Comment: I really appreciate it @Tiger-222!  I am a beginner so your help with regular expressions and my code is highly appreciated. I am learning. Do you happen to know why my match is erroring? I did the "from re import compile,match"

Comment: @Emily post your entire code with the XLSX file, what the error, what you get and what you want. It is not easy to guess. Update your question to give all informations to helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be doing the right thing, with the exception that you want it to **print** the value of *line* instead of the value of *list_nums*.

Another approach to the task at hand, would be to use regular expressions, which are ideal for pattern recognition.

**EDIT: CODE NOW ASSUMES list_nums TO BE A SINGLE STRING**

```
import re

rx = re.compile('\d{6}-\d{2}\Z')
for line in list_nums.split('\n'):
  if rx.match(line):
    print line
```

Comment: hm. match doesn't work..... says it's not being used. i said "from re import compile, match" but nothing.

Comment: Okay. Running the code on the list **list_nums = ['123456-56','123456-98-98']** yields the result **'123456-56'** in my system - note that _match_ is called on the _RegexObject_ **rx** not the library **re**.

Comment: is that because yours is a set/list? mine is just a string, it will finish the code successfully but not output anything

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string? - how is it formatted

Comment: 581094-001
581095-001
581096-001
581097-01
5586987-007
SMX53-5567-53BP
552392-01-01
552392-02
552392-03-01
552392-10-01
552392-10-01
580062
580063
580065
580065
580066
543921-01
556664-55

Comment: but all "\n" new line

Comment: I have updated the code, if it does not work, you will need to change the argument of **list_nums.split( )** to the separator used in your string.